# How Does hibernate First Level Caching Works With @Transactional On DAO Class

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

**Things i Know:**
hibernate first level Caching is Auto Enabled and are Session Specific.

I have this Below class, I just Want to Check Whether First Level Caching is Working Or Not.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class StudentDaoImpl implements ServiceDao {
    /**
     * The EntityManager invokes
     * the hibernate session under the hood.
     */
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public <T> List<T> fetchAll(Class<T> type) {
        // entityManager.unwrap creates a new Session if it does not exist

        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> query = builder.createQuery(type);

        // getting All data from Table
        query.from(type);
        List<T> list = session.createQuery(query).getResultList(); // 1st query gets fired
        List<T> list1 = session.createQuery(query).getResultList(); // 2nd query gets fired
        return list;

    }
```

i Was Expecting that only one query will get fired, but 2 Queries are getting fired, Even though we are in the Same Session (if am not Wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session cache caches entities by ID. If you call `entityManager.find()` twice with the same ID, only 1 query will be executed.

Caching queries can only be done with a query cache. Without that, executing a query will always... execute the query.

Note that the JPA API allows creating a criteria query without unwrapping the session.

Comment: can you please explain how can i achieve **JPA API allows creating a criteria query without unwrapping the session** this

Comment: You're calling getCriteriaBuilder() and createQuery() on the Session. Call them directly on the EntityManager. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery-, https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getCriteriaBuilder--.